# How to update Toast value?

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to update the toast value at different instances in my code.
I tried to instantiate an object like this:

```
 Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

and update its value whenever I needed inside my code. Like this:

```
mToast.setText("Hello!");
```

The initial instantiation seems to be crashing my code.

Any clues why this would happen?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace that gets output to Logcat when the app crashes?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I know that the crash is because Toast is a UI element and needs to belong with one. It cannot be instantiated by itself. Alexandre Martin's solution might be the simplest one. I'm going to give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app crash when you instantiate your Toast, it could be for the wrong context in the constructor.
Where do you declare it? be sure to get your real context.

You can't update the Toast for real, but you can hide the toast and make a new one.
Use `mToast.cancel();` to remove your Toast, then

```
mToast.setText("New text");
mToast.show();
```

Comment: It doesn't work either on Samsung Galaxy S3 or Emulator API 25. When `mToast.cancel()` is called, the same `mToast` can't be `show` anymore. If `mToast.cancel()` is not called it works well with one Toast, but if I have multiple instances - I experience glitches.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function which receives a string message and display it.

```
public void showToast(String message) {

    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

And call it wherever you want :

```
showToast("My message");
```

EDIT

To update a Toast while displayed :

```
Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//...

mToast.cancel();
mToast.setText("Updated text");
mToast.show();
```

It works for me, so please provide any error message you've got :)

Comment: My problem is that it does not update the text if a previous text is already on the screen!

Comment: It will display after. You can call `cancel()` to get rid of Toasts already showing

Comment: Where do I use 'cancel()' ? Is it the first line of the function?

Comment: The crash happens at the mToast instantiation. So, I don't have mToast to update it.

Comment: Does your first parameter refer to the activity context ? Maybe 'this' is in a listener ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115901/discussion-between-vahid-zadeh-and-alexandre-martin).